# Asignamiento de ID y class en JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, class

soy nuevo en esto de programar, tengo un problema, y es que tengo que crear un menu desde JS sin tocar el HTML, mas o menos ya lo he acabado, pero necesito añadir a cada etiqueta una ID y una class para poder manipularlas luego
Alguien me podría decir un método de JS para hacerlo? Gracias de antemano ; )

Comment: debes publicar lo que haz hecho para poder ayudarte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El metodo SetAttribute te puede ayudar, lo que debes de hacer es buscar al elemento que le pondras el atributo y como primer parametro debes de ponerle que atributo es, y como segundo el valor

EJEMPLO:

```
Elemento.setAttribute('class','ElnombreDeMiClase')
```

EJEMPLO2:

```
Elemento.setAttribute('id', 'NombreDeMiId')
```

En estos casos Elemento esta tomando el papel de una variable piensa que el Elemento es algo como esto

```
var Elemento = document.getElementById('div')
```